# How can I generate rows in a SQL table to break up a range into induvidual rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

I have data with info similar to the below:

```
Customer  Start   End
AAA        100    399 
BBB        400    899
CCC        900    999  
AAA        1000   1199
```

What I need it to become is 2 Columns, 1 with customer name and the other with each value within the range. I.E.

```
Customer    Number
AAA           100
AAA           101
AAA           102   ETC
```

How can this be written in SQL?

Comment: Have a cte that produces all possible numbers. Join.

Comment: What rdbms are you using? sql is a general language and each database use it's own specific dialect - so whenever asking questions about sql, be sure to include the tag for the relevant rdbms. It's also always good to include the tag for the specific version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach I would recommend is to go for recursive with CTE. Please find the following code snippet to do it.

```
declare @source table (customer varchar(15), rangeStart int, rangeEnd int)

insert into @source (customer, rangeStart, rangeEnd)
select 'AAA', 100, 399
union
select 'BBB', 400, 899
union
select 'CCC', 900, 999
union
select 'AAA', 1000, 1199


select * from @source

; with results as (
    select Customer, rangeStart, rangeEnd, rangeNumber = rangeStart
        from @source
    union all
    select Customer, rangeStart, rangeEnd, rangeNumber + 1
        from results
        where rangeNumber <= rangeEnd

)

select * 
    from results 
    order by rangeNumber
    option (MAXRECURSION 20000)
```

Comment: Using a recursive cte like that is far from being the best idea - for more information, read Jeff Moden's [Hidden RBAR: Counting with Recursive CTE's](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a numbers table, use it. If not, you can generate a numbers table on the fly using a cte.

First, create and populate sample table(**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    Customer char(3),
    Start int,
    [End] int
);

INSERT INTO @T(Customer, Start, [End]) VALUES
('AAA', 100, 399), 
('BBB', 400, 899),
('CCC', 900, 999),  
('AAA', 1000, 1199);
```

Then, use a cte to generate the numbers you need

```
WITH Tally(n) AS
(
    SELECT TOP(select max([End]) from @T) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@SPID) 
    FROM sys.objects
)
```

Finally, select from the table joined to the cte:

```
SELECT Customer, n
FROM @T
JOIN Tally 
    ON n >= Start
    AND n <= [End]
ORDER BY Customer, n
```