# Populating rows based on the value in that row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to generate Serial Numbers for items currently in a batch.

I generated the serial numbers using the following code:

```
--insert into SerialMF  (
--  SerialNumber
--, SNStockLink
--, SNDateLMove
--, CurrentLoc
--, CurrentAccLink
--, iSNLotID
--, iSNMFPID
--, iSNMFPLineID
--, SerialMF_iBranchID
--)
select
    'StockOut'+cast(iStockID as varchar)+'_'+right(replicate('0',3)+cast(rank() over (partition by iStockID order by iStockID) as varchar),3)   SerialNumber
,   iStockID                        --  SNStockLink
,   getdate()                       --  SNDateLMove
,   1                               --  CurrentLoc
,   iWarehouseID                    --  CurrentAccLink
,   0                               --  iSNLotID
,   0                               --  iSNMFPID
,   0                               --  iSNMFPLineID
,   _etblInvJrBatchLines_iBranchID  --  SerialMF_iBranchID
,   fQtyOut
from
( 
  select * from _etblInvJrBatchLines
  where iInvJrBatchID = 1 and bIsSerialItem = 1
)b
left outer join
(
  select * from SerialMF
)s  on  b.iStockID  =   s.SNStockLink
where SNStockLink is null
```

From the above, it generates the Serial Numbers correctly, however I realized that it did not generate the Serial Numbers to the amount of the actual quantity of that item.

I need Serial Numbers generated for each quantity of that particular item, however the Serial Number needs to be different for each of the quantities.

The current rows returned in the database is 1865, however the following sample data is for your reference and assistance (100 rows):

```
SerialNumber       iStockID  getdate()  (No column name)    iWarehouseID    (No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)    _etblInvJrBatchLines_iBranchID  fQtyOut
StockOut63041_001   63041   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63042_001   63042   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63043_001   63043   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63044_001   63044   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63045_001   63045   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63046_001   63046   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63047_001   63047   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63048_001   63048   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63049_001   63049   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63050_001   63050   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63051_001   63051   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63052_001   63052   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   6
StockOut63053_001   63053   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63054_001   63054   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63055_001   63055   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63056_001   63056   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   9
StockOut63057_001   63057   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   4
StockOut63058_001   63058   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63059_001   63059   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63060_001   63060   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63061_001   63061   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63062_001   63062   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63063_001   63063   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63064_001   63064   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63065_001   63065   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63066_001   63066   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63067_001   63067   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   6
StockOut63068_001   63068   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63069_001   63069   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63070_001   63070   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63071_001   63071   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63072_001   63072   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63073_001   63073   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63074_001   63074   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63075_001   63075   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   5
StockOut63076_001   63076   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63077_001   63077   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   5
StockOut63078_001   63078   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   4
StockOut63079_001   63079   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63080_001   63080   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63081_001   63081   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63082_001   63082   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63083_001   63083   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63084_001   63084   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   4
StockOut63085_001   63085   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63089_001   63089   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63090_001   63090   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63091_001   63091   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63092_001   63092   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63093_001   63093   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63094_001   63094   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63095_001   63095   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63096_001   63096   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63097_001   63097   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63098_001   63098   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63099_001   63099   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   14
StockOut63100_001   63100   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63101_001   63101   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   4
StockOut63102_001   63102   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63104_001   63104   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63105_001   63105   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63106_001   63106   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63107_001   63107   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63108_001   63108   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   7
StockOut63109_001   63109   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63110_001   63110   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63111_001   63111   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   5
StockOut63112_001   63112   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63113_001   63113   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63114_001   63114   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63115_001   63115   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63116_001   63116   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63117_001   63117   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63118_001   63118   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63119_001   63119   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63120_001   63120   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63121_001   63121   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63122_001   63122   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63123_001   63123   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63124_001   63124   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63125_001   63125   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63126_001   63126   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63127_001   63127   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63128_001   63128   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63129_001   63129   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63130_001   63130   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63131_001   63131   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63132_001   63132   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63133_001   63133   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63134_001   63134   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63135_001   63135   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63136_001   63136   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63137_001   63137   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63138_001   63138   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63140_001   63140   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63141_001   63141   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63142_001   63142   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   8
StockOut63143_001   63143   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63144_001   63144   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63145_001   63145   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   5
```

How do I generate rows for each of the quantities specified with a different Serial Number for each Quantity?

My Expected Results would look like following:

```
SerialNumber    iStockID    getdate()   (No column name)    iWarehouseID    (No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)    _etblInvJrBatchLines_iBranchID  fQtyOut
StockOut63041_001   63041   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63041_002   63041   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63042_001   63042   19/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63042_002   63042   19/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63043_001   63043   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63044_001   63044   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63044_002   63044   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63045_001   63045   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63045_002   63045   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63046_001   63046   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63047_001   63047   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63048_001   63048   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63049_001   63049   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63050_001   63050   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63050_002   63050   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63050_003   63050   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63051_001   63051   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63052_001   63052   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   6
StockOut63052_002   63052   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   6
StockOut63052_003   63052   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   6
StockOut63052_004   63052   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   6
StockOut63052_005   63052   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   6
StockOut63052_006   63052   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   6
StockOut63053_001   63053   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63054_001   63054   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63054_002   63054   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63054_003   63054   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63055_001   63055   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63056_001   63056   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   9
StockOut63056_002   63056   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   9
StockOut63056_003   63056   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   9
StockOut63056_004   63056   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   9
StockOut63056_005   63056   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   9
StockOut63056_006   63056   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   9
StockOut63056_007   63056   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   9
StockOut63056_008   63056   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   9
StockOut63056_009   63056   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   9
StockOut63057_001   63057   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   4
StockOut63057_002   63057   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   4
StockOut63057_003   63057   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   4
StockOut63057_004   63057   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   4
StockOut63058_001   63058   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63058_002   63058   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63059_001   63059   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63060_001   63060   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63060_002   63060   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63060_003   63060   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63061_001   63061   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63062_001   63062   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63062_002   63062   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63063_001   63063   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63064_001   63064   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63064_002   63064   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63065_001   63065   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63066_001   63066   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63067_001   63067   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   6
StockOut63067_002   63067   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   6
StockOut63067_003   63067   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   6
StockOut63067_004   63067   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   6
StockOut63067_005   63067   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   6
StockOut63067_006   63067   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   6
StockOut63068_001   63068   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63068_002   63068   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63069_001   63069   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63069_002   63069   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63069_003   63069   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63070_001   63070   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63071_001   63071   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63071_002   63071   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63072_001   63072   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63073_001   63073   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63073_002   63073   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63074_001   63074   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63074_002   63074   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63074_003   63074   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63075_001   63075   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   5
StockOut63075_002   63075   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   5
StockOut63075_003   63075   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   5
StockOut63075_004   63075   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   5
StockOut63075_005   63075   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   5
StockOut63076_001   63076   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63076_002   63076   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63077_001   63077   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   5
StockOut63077_002   63077   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   5
StockOut63077_003   63077   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   5
StockOut63077_004   63077   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   5
StockOut63077_005   63077   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   5
StockOut63078_001   63078   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   4
StockOut63078_002   63078   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   4
StockOut63078_003   63078   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   4
StockOut63078_004   63078   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   4
StockOut63079_001   63079   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63080_001   63080   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63081_001   63081   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63082_001   63082   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63083_001   63083   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63083_002   63083   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63083_003   63083   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63084_001   63084   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   4
StockOut63084_002   63084   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   4
StockOut63084_003   63084   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   4
StockOut63084_004   63084   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   4
StockOut63085_001   63085   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63089_001   63089   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63089_002   63089   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63090_001   63090   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63090_002   63090   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63090_003   63090   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63091_001   63091   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63092_001   63092   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63093_001   63093   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63094_001   63094   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63095_001   63095   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63096_001   63096   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63097_001   63097   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63098_001   63098   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63098_002   63098   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63098_003   63098   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63099_001   63099   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   14
StockOut63099_002   63099   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   14
StockOut63099_003   63099   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   14
StockOut63099_004   63099   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   14
StockOut63099_005   63099   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   14
StockOut63099_006   63099   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   14
StockOut63099_007   63099   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   14
StockOut63099_008   63099   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   14
StockOut63099_009   63099   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   14
StockOut63099_010   63099   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   14
StockOut63099_011   63099   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   14
StockOut63099_012   63099   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   14
StockOut63099_013   63099   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   14
StockOut63099_014   63099   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   14
StockOut63100_001   63100   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63101_001   63101   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   4
StockOut63101_002   63101   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   4
StockOut63101_003   63101   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   4
StockOut63101_004   63101   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   4
StockOut63102_001   63102   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63104_001   63104   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63104_002   63104   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63105_001   63105   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63106_001   63106   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63107_001   63107   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63107_002   63107   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63107_003   63107   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63108_001   63108   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   7
StockOut63108_002   63108   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   7
StockOut63108_003   63108   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   7
StockOut63108_004   63108   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   7
StockOut63108_005   63108   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   7
StockOut63108_006   63108   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   7
StockOut63108_007   63108   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   7
StockOut63109_001   63109   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63110_001   63110   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63111_001   63111   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   5
StockOut63111_002   63111   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   5
StockOut63111_003   63111   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   5
StockOut63111_004   63111   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   5
StockOut63111_005   63111   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   5
StockOut63112_001   63112   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63113_001   63113   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63114_001   63114   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63115_001   63115   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63115_002   63115   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63115_003   63115   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63116_001   63116   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63117_001   63117   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63118_001   63118   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63119_001   63119   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63119_002   63119   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63120_001   63120   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63121_001   63121   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63122_001   63122   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63123_001   63123   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63124_001   63124   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63125_001   63125   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63126_001   63126   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63127_001   63127   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63127_002   63127   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63128_001   63128   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63128_002   63128   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63129_001   63129   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63130_001   63130   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63131_001   63131   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63132_001   63132   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63132_002   63132   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63132_003   63132   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   3
StockOut63133_001   63133   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63133_002   63133   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   2
StockOut63134_001   63134   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63135_001   63135   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63136_001   63136   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63137_001   63137   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63138_001   63138   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63140_001   63140   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63141_001   63141   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63142_001   63142   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   8
StockOut63142_002   63142   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   8
StockOut63142_003   63142   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   8
StockOut63142_004   63142   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   8
StockOut63142_005   63142   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   8
StockOut63142_006   63142   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   8
StockOut63142_007   63142   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   8
StockOut63142_008   63142   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   8
StockOut63143_001   63143   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63144_001   63144   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   1
StockOut63145_001   63145   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   5
StockOut63145_002   63145   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   5
StockOut63145_003   63145   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   5
StockOut63145_004   63145   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   5
StockOut63145_005   63145   18/12/2018  1   479 0   0   0   0   5
```

Notice that every Serial Number is unique based on the quantity...

Comment: Please don't post data as an image, it's not helpful to the volunteers trying to help you. Provide it as formatted `text`, or as DDL (`CREATE`) and DML (`INSERT`) statements. When you edit your post, can you also ensure you explain the logic behind getting from your sample data to your expected results please.

Comment: I've altered my question as per your request @Larnu. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: We don't have sample data and expected results now. Just expected results? Without knowing what your data looked like before, answering will be hard. Have a look at my answer based on your original requirement, where I create a dataset with your data. You might want to use DDL (`CREATE`) and DML (`INSERT`) statements, rather than what I call a "VTE" (*Values* Table Expression).

Comment: I agree @Larnu, however the above is actually the sample data. I will add my expected results shortly to my question - (have to manually populate it in Excel quickly)

Comment: @Larnu, I've added my expected results. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting this as a different answer, as the question has been significantly changed since the OP initially asked their question.

Anyway, this get's the OP what they are after. I've used an inline tally table this time, rather than the View:

```
--Created table only with the relevant columns for the OP's question
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (SerialNumber varchar(20),
                            iStockID int,
                            fQtyOut tinyint);
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (SerialNumber,
                           iStockID,
                           fQtyOut)
VALUES ('StockOut63041_001',63041,2 ),
       ('StockOut63042_001',63042,1 ),
       ('StockOut63043_001',63043,1 ),
       ('StockOut63044_001',63044,2 ),
       ('StockOut63045_001',63045,2 ),
       ('StockOut63046_001',63046,1 ),
       ('StockOut63047_001',63047,1 ),
       ('StockOut63048_001',63048,1 ),
       ('StockOut63049_001',63049,1 ),
       ('StockOut63050_001',63050,3 ),
       ('StockOut63051_001',63051,1 ),
       ('StockOut63052_001',63052,6 ),
       ('StockOut63053_001',63053,1 ),
       ('StockOut63054_001',63054,3 ),
       ('StockOut63055_001',63055,1 ),
       ('StockOut63056_001',63056,9 ),
       ('StockOut63057_001',63057,4 ),
       ('StockOut63058_001',63058,2 ),
       ('StockOut63059_001',63059,1 ),
       ('StockOut63060_001',63060,3 ),
       ('StockOut63061_001',63061,1 ),
       ('StockOut63062_001',63062,2 ),
       ('StockOut63063_001',63063,1 ),
       ('StockOut63064_001',63064,2 ),
       ('StockOut63065_001',63065,1 ),
       ('StockOut63066_001',63066,1 ),
       ('StockOut63067_001',63067,6 ),
       ('StockOut63068_001',63068,2 ),
       ('StockOut63069_001',63069,3 ),
       ('StockOut63070_001',63070,1 ),
       ('StockOut63071_001',63071,2 ),
       ('StockOut63072_001',63072,1 ),
       ('StockOut63073_001',63073,2 ),
       ('StockOut63074_001',63074,3 ),
       ('StockOut63075_001',63075,5 ),
       ('StockOut63076_001',63076,2 ),
       ('StockOut63077_001',63077,5 ),
       ('StockOut63078_001',63078,4 ),
       ('StockOut63079_001',63079,1 ),
       ('StockOut63080_001',63080,1 ),
       ('StockOut63081_001',63081,1 ),
       ('StockOut63082_001',63082,1 ),
       ('StockOut63083_001',63083,3 ),
       ('StockOut63084_001',63084,4 ),
       ('StockOut63085_001',63085,1 ),
       ('StockOut63089_001',63089,2 ),
       ('StockOut63090_001',63090,3 ),
       ('StockOut63091_001',63091,1 ),
       ('StockOut63092_001',63092,1 ),
       ('StockOut63093_001',63093,1 ),
       ('StockOut63094_001',63094,1 ),
       ('StockOut63095_001',63095,1 ),
       ('StockOut63096_001',63096,1 ),
       ('StockOut63097_001',63097,1 ),
       ('StockOut63098_001',63098,3 ),
       ('StockOut63099_001',63099,14),
       ('StockOut63100_001',63100,1 ),
       ('StockOut63101_001',63101,4 ),
       ('StockOut63102_001',63102,1 ),
       ('StockOut63104_001',63104,2 ),
       ('StockOut63105_001',63105,1 ),
       ('StockOut63106_001',63106,1 ),
       ('StockOut63107_001',63107,3 ),
       ('StockOut63108_001',63108,7 ),
       ('StockOut63109_001',63109,1 ),
       ('StockOut63110_001',63110,1 ),
       ('StockOut63111_001',63111,5 ),
       ('StockOut63112_001',63112,1 ),
       ('StockOut63113_001',63113,1 ),
       ('StockOut63114_001',63114,1 ),
       ('StockOut63115_001',63115,3 ),
       ('StockOut63116_001',63116,1 ),
       ('StockOut63117_001',63117,1 ),
       ('StockOut63118_001',63118,1 ),
       ('StockOut63119_001',63119,2 ),
       ('StockOut63120_001',63120,1 ),
       ('StockOut63121_001',63121,1 ),
       ('StockOut63122_001',63122,1 ),
       ('StockOut63123_001',63123,1 ),
       ('StockOut63124_001',63124,1 ),
       ('StockOut63125_001',63125,1 ),
       ('StockOut63126_001',63126,1 ),
       ('StockOut63127_001',63127,2 ),
       ('StockOut63128_001',63128,2 ),
       ('StockOut63129_001',63129,2 ),
       ('StockOut63130_001',63130,1 ),
       ('StockOut63131_001',63131,1 ),
       ('StockOut63132_001',63132,3 ),
       ('StockOut63133_001',63133,2 ),
       ('StockOut63134_001',63134,1 ),
       ('StockOut63135_001',63135,1 ),
       ('StockOut63136_001',63136,1 ),
       ('StockOut63137_001',63137,1 ),
       ('StockOut63138_001',63138,1 ),
       ('StockOut63140_001',63140,1 ),
       ('StockOut63141_001',63141,1 ),
       ('StockOut63142_001',63142,8 ),
       ('StockOut63143_001',63143,1 ),
       ('StockOut63144_001',63144,1 ),
       ('StockOut63145_001',63145,5 );

GO

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) I
    FROM N N1
         CROSS JOIN N N2
         CROSS JOIN N N3),
CTE AS(
    SELECT YT.SerialNumber,
           YT.iStockID,
           YT.fQtyOut,
           V.SerialPrefix,
           CONVERT(int,V.SerialSuffix) AS SerialSuffix
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PARSENAME(REPLACE(YT.SerialNumber,'_','.'),2),PARSENAME(REPLACE(YT.SerialNumber,'_','.'),1))) V(SerialPrefix,SerialSuffix))
SELECT C.SerialPrefix + '_' + RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(varchar(3),C.SerialSuffix + T.I - 1),3) AS SerialNumber,
       C.iStockID,
       C.fQtyOut
FROM CTE C
     JOIN Tally T ON C.fQtyOut >= T.I
ORDER BY iStockID;


GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: Thank you @Larnu, I have copied your answer and made some changes to it on my side to insert the data from the database into the `YourTable` table, however, when running it now, I get the follwowing error `Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type varchar.` The only change I made is change your code from `tinyint` for the `fQtyOut` to `float`. What may I be doing wrong?

Comment: O and I also created the extra necessary columns for that table I require.

Comment: I'm thinking of posting my code as one of the answers, then you can maybe just alter my answer for it to work?

Comment: If I change `tinyint` to `float`, I don't get the error you have; so you must have done something else. Don't post an erronous answer; use something like db<>fiddle @Birel .

Answer (score 2):

One method would be to use a Tally table, like the one as a view in this [article (vTally)](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calendar/145206/).

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (63564,1 ),
                 (66669,1 ),
                 (66814,4 ),
                 (63707,1 ),
                 (63708,1 ),
                 (63221,1 ),
                 (63222,1 ),
                 (63223,1 ),
                 (63224,1 ),
                 (63226,3 ),
                 (63225,7 ),
                 (63227,1 ),
                 (63228,1 ),
                 (53498,2 ),
                 (53498,2 ),
                 (63230,1 ),
                 (63445,1 ),
                 (63232,1 ),
                 (39478,1 ),
                 (63636,7 ),
                 (63637,1 ),
                 (63638,14),
                 (63639,1 ),
                 (63523,1 ),
                 (63524,3 ),
                 (63525,2 ),
                 (63526,1 ),
                 (63403,1 ),
                 (63404,1 ),
                 (63405,13),
                 (63406,14),
                 (63710,1 ),
                 (63711,1 ),
                 (63712,1 ),
                 (63713,2 ),
                 (63714,1 ),
                 (63715,2 ),
                 (63716,1 ),
                 (63717,1 ),
                 (63718,1 ),
                 (63719,1 ),
                 (63720,1 ),
                 (63721,1 ),
                 (66385,2 ),
                 (52162,1 ),
                 (42458,1 ),
                 (43590,1 ),
                 (63396,1 ),
                 (63397,1 ),
                 (63398,5 )) V(iStockID, fQtyOut))
SELECT V.iStockID,
       V.fQtyOut
FROM VTE V
     JOIN dbo.vTally T ON V.fQtyOut >= T.N
WHERE V.iStockID = 66814;
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use a `VIEW`, or physical table, you could use a CTE to create an inline tally table:

```
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) I
    FROM N N1
         CROSS JOIN N N2
         CROSS JOIN N N3)
SELECT V.iStockID,
       V.fQtyOut
FROM VTE V --Assumes VTE was declared, i just haven't repeated the code
     JOIN Tally T ON V.fQtyOut >= T.I
WHERE V.iStockID = 66814;
```

Comment: I was just in the process of posting more or less the same answer... +1

Comment: Thanks for your assistance @Larnu, however I'm having trouble understanding your query a bit. Could I perhaps modify my question, for you to have a look at it again?

Comment: [I knew I've answered something this not so long ago...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53155722/how-can-i-generate-rows-in-a-sql-table-to-break-up-a-range-into-induvidual-rows/53156600#53156600)

Comment: What bit is it you don't understand about the SQL, @Birel ? Please do feel free to update your question if you don't think its covering your needs. When asking, try to be very specific on your requirement; then there's far less chance for misunderstanding/misinterpretation

Comment: Understood @Larnu, apologies for any inconvenience caused and thanks again for your assistance. I've updated my question...

Comment: I managed to fix the 
>Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type varchar. 
error by changing your code from `SELECT C.SerialPrefix + '_' + RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(varchar(3),C.SerialSuffix + T.I - 1),3) AS SerialNumber,` to `SELECT C.SerialPrefix + '_' + RIGHT('000' + cast(C.SerialSuffix + T.I - 1 as varchar),3) AS SerialNumber,` 

Thanks again for your assistance!

Comment: @Larnu, any idea why it stops populating serial numbers at a 1000 when a qty is actually 1123? Should it not continue populating the Serial Counter until 1123?

Comment: The inline tally table only goes up to 1000. You'll need to use more `CROSS JOIN`'s to get more rows. note that the above won't work for other reasons for a quantity of 1000 or more, due to your sample data **heavily** implying that you would have at most a 3 figure number.